# Объект из БД в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net, ssms

Имеется объект *WorkingTime*:

```
public partial class WorkingTime
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TimeStart { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeEnd { get; set; }

    public virtual Employees Employees { get; set; }
}
```

И объект *Employees*

```
public partial class Employees
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Employees()
    {
        this.WorkingTime = new HashSet<WorkingTime>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<WorkingTime> WorkingTime { get; set; }
}
```

На форме задаю значения *TimeStart* и *TimeEnd* при помощи 2-ух *DatePicker* и 2-ух *TextBox*.
Employees выбираю из ComboBox:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="0,5">
            <Label Content="Сотрудник:" Width="140"/>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllEmployees}" SelectedItem="{Binding WorkingObject.Employees}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Surname}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </DockPanel>
```

Почему при выборе WorkingTime.Employees значение WorkingTime.EmployeeID не выбирается из Employees.ID?

Comment: Укажите точную версию EF. / Модификатор `virtual` используется при ленивой загрузке (lazy loading). Она включена?

Comment: Подсказка: не используйте `Label`, ее в WPF никто не использует, используйте `TextBlock`

Comment: Версия EF - 6.2.0. Ленивую загрузку нигде не включал. Она включена по умолчанию ?
Изменил Label на TextBlock в ComboBox - Проблема не решилась.

Comment: Судя по номеру, это обычный EF, без Core. Значит ленивая загрузка включена по умолчанию. / Она может быть отключена вручную. Поищите в своём коде (поиск по всему проекту) упоминание [LazyLoadingEnabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#turn-off-lazy-loading-for-all-entities)

Comment: Нашел упоминание LazyLoadingEnabled в файле Model.Context.tt Код следующий:
`if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}`
И в файле Model.edmx :
`<EntityContainer Name="MainEntities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">`.
Изменил значение в файле Model.edmx на false - ничего не изменилось

Comment: `false` отключает ленивую загрузку, а её наоборот нужно включить. Ещё лучше использовать энергичную загрузку (Eagerly Loading). Смотрите документацию: [Loading Related Entities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data). / Но вообще, проблема может быть вовсе не в этом.

Comment: включение ленивой загрузки не помогло, буду пытаться определить в чем проблема.